# How do i transition between views, each having their own view controller?

Tags: ios, view

I created a single view application on X-Code and created another view controller and tried pushing the second view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{   
if (self.statesView == nil)
{
    StatesView *newStateView = [[StatesView alloc]initWithNibName:@"StatesView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.statesView = newStateView;
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.statesView animated:YES];
}
```

But the application crashes with SIGABRT signal

Comment: please provide more details (what the crash error, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Is StatesView a ViewController ?
`pushViewController:` needs a `UIViewController`, not a `UIView`.

I think you are trying to change ViewController when you are tapping a row in a UITableView.
The easier and best way to achieve this is to use segues. In your storyboard, ctrl drag your `UITableViewCell` and link it with your new view controller.

If you want to do it programmatically, you need to use :

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StatesViewController"];
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it without the storyboard

Comment: @user730304 Do you have any reason not to use Storyboards ? Moreover, you ought to change your class name to something which ends with "ViewController".

Answer (score 0):

So, your `StatesView` instance (i.e. `newStateView`) is a UIView subclass, so it's a view, not a controller. You can only use `pushViewController` when you send an `UIViewController` subclass to it. You can add your the `newStateView` to the current view using :

```
[self.view addSubview:self.statesView];
```

But that does it without any transition. You can animate view properties using `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]`

Comment: My States view is a sub class of UIViewController itself.

Comment: Oh, ok, can you tell me what does the crash message say?

Comment: Program received signal. SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

you can animate the transition between views like this 

`CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //choose your animation
[viewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.viewController1.view addSubview:viewController2.view];`

 dont forget to import the QuartzCore lib !!